# Proving an Inequality

Tags: inequality

Suppose I've got a positive number $a$>0.
I've got some other positive number $b$>0.

I am given that $a$ > $b$.

How do I prove that the above implies $-a + \sqrt{ a^{2} - b^{2} }$ < 0 ?

So far I have found that:

$a>b \implies a^2 >b^2 \implies \sqrt{ a^2 - b^2 } > 0$

Another thought I had was to use the above to show that $a^2>a^2-b^2$, from which the required result should follow.

This is such an elementary task but I can't seem to find a way to prove this.

Comment: $b^2>0$ since $b>0$. Now what can you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that for any $x > 0$, we have $x^2 > 0$. Then we have the chain

$$ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} - a < 0 \iff \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} < a \iff a^2 - b^2 < a^2 \iff 0 < b^2,$$
and we know the last inequality is true.

Comment: Thank you! The last $\iff$ is exactly the detail I've been missing.